# rxjs concatenating observables

Tags: arrays, rxjs, concatenation, fork-join

I want to combine 2 observable arrays using this code.

```
this.filterValues$[filterName] = concat(
  of(this.initialValues), // ['1', '2', '3']
  this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey) // ['4', '5', '6']
).pipe(
  tap(res => console.log(res) // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
)
```

Here it logs 2 arrays but I'm not sure how to merge them together. I also tried `forkjoin`, `merge` without success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way do you want to combine/merge two arrays? Post some example input and output.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Does `this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey)` emit only once or multiple times?

Comment: Yes, if that means it is called multiple times

Comment: Please share the code within getFilterValues method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combineLatest` to get latest values from each observable and then do something with the values.
For example:

```js
import { Subject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


console.clear();

const subject1 = new Subject<number[]>();
const subject2 = new Subject<number[]>();

const merged = combineLatest(subject1, subject2)
  .pipe(
    map(combined => {
      const firstArray = combined[0];
      const secondArray = combined[1];
      return firstArray.concat(secondArray)
      })
    )
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

console.log('inital values for both arrays')
subject1.next([1,2])
subject2.next([3,4])
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log('update first array')
subject1.next([5,6])
// [5, 6, 3, 4]

console.log('update second array')
subject2.next([7,8])
// [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

We combine both observables into one value (which is an array) and then merge them into one array manually.

This could be written more concisely as

```js
const concise = combineLatest(subject1, subject2).pipe(
  map(([first, second]) => first.concat(second)),
);
```

Check this code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2mxdu3)

Note that `combineLatest` will NOT emit anything until BOTH observables have emitted a value. If you have some sort of default value for one of the observables, you could use the `startWith` operator like so:

```js
const concise = combineLatest(
  subject1,
  subject2.pipe(startWith([0,0])),
  )
  .pipe(
    map(([first, second]) => first.concat(second)),
  ).subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehy,

i assume that you just need to emit the final version of the array and not the partials. So this should work for you:

```
this.filterValues$[filterName] = concat(
  of(this.initialValues), // ['1', '2', '3']
  this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey) // ['4', '5', '6']
).pipe(
  reduce( (all, result) => [...all, ...result], []),
  tap(res => console.log(res) // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
)
```

[here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) something more about the `reduce` operator.

Comment: So it should be something related to the observable coming from this `this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey)`. Because [it should work like that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kadbhw) otherwise. Can you check if it completes or it emits value alone ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scan`

if they emit numbers (not arrays).

```js
this.filterValues$[filterName] = concat(
  of(this.initialValues), // ['1', '2', '3']
  this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey) // ['4', '5', '6']
).pipe(
  scan((r, i) => [...r, i], []),
  tap(res => console.log(res) // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
)
```

if they emit arrays of numbers.

```js
this.filterValues$[filterName] = concat(
  of(this.initialValues), // ['1', '2', '3']
  this.getFilterValues(filterName, this.afterKey) // ['4', '5', '6']
).pipe(
  scan((r, i) => [...r, ...i], []),
  tap(res => console.log(res) // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
)
```